How to make ruff ignore comments in measuring the line length?
The line
demo_code = print("foo bar")  # some comments and this line length exceed 79 that i config.

is being formatted by ruff format to
demo_code = print(
    "foo bar"
)  # some comments and this line length exceed 79 that i config.

as it exceeds the value defined in line-length.
I want to make ruff count only command characters and ignore the comments.

The best (unique?) solution to ignore lengthy code line errors (E501) with ruff is using codetags in you code:
# pyproject.toml
[tool.ruff.lint.pycodestyle]
ignore-overlong-task-comments = true

[tool.ruff.lint]
task-tags = ["HACK"]

demo_code = print("foo bar")  # HACK: That is a so savvy solution. Now, I can write very lengthy inline comments without any problem :)


As of September 2024, Ruff does not support ignoring comments within the line length rule (E501). The following issue (along with related issues here and here) is tracking the addition of flake8-length into ruff which would provide support for this.
In the mean time, you could consider disabling the rule, letting your formatter automatically break up lines longer than your configured line length and not worrying about exceptions. To do this, modify your pyproject.toml to include:
[tool.ruff.lint]
ignore = ["E501"]

